# How to generate palettes that display a range of saturation/color in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects

In Photoshop, I took one color (the pixel in the top left corner) and drew the rest of this palette by changing hue/saturation.

[image]

I want to recreate this same palette but with other colors, but I do not want to fiddle with hue/saturation values for every color.

How can I use this palette to create another palette with identical hue/saturation differences with a different color in Photoshop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just change the hue over the entire image for different colors (they will all adjust proportionately)

I just added an adjustment layer for **Hue/Saturation** and adjusted it.

[image: hue changing]

Comment: I tried this out before posting, but wasn't able to get an exact palette match for my desired color.  Is there a way to adjust the hue/saturation layer to match a specific color?

Comment: Tick the `Colorize` option @nine-hundred Your foreground color will be used as the starting point.